# Windows phone 8 array binding don't seems to change

Tags: c#, arrays, mvvm, binding, windows-phone-8

EDIT: changes to a Observable collection as it was sugested, but still don't work:
New code looks like:

```
    private ObservableCollection<bool> _placeTypes = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
    //private static bool[] _placeTypes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<bool> placeTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _placeTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            _placeTypes = value;
            placechange = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged("placeTypes");
        }
    }
```

Oki, I have an object with a bool array with this structure:

```
    private bool[] _placeTypes { get; set; }
    public bool[] placeTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _placeTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            _placeTypes = value;
            placechange = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged("placeTypes");
        }
    }
```

The object is binded correctly to some checkboxes in this way:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="_1_Cafe" IsChecked="{Binding Path=placeTypes[0], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Cafe" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
<CheckBox x:Name="_2_Pub" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[1], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Pub" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="_3_Chiringuito" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[2], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Chiringuito" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="_4_BeachClub" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[3], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Beach Club" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="_5_ClubDiscoteca" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[4], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Club/Discoteca" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="_6_Tetería" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[5], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Tetería" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="_7_Restaurante" IsChecked="{Binding placeTypes[6], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Restaurante" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="429"/>
```

And I need to know if they changed or not to send a Json package with this method:

```
if (Perfil.placechange == true)
        {
            int[] places = new int[7];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (Perfil.placeTypes[i] == true)
                {
                    places[i] = i + 1;
                }
            }
            preferencias.placeTypes = places;
            launch = true;
        }
        paquete.preferencias = preferencias;
        if (launch == true)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("link");
            string respuesta = await metodosJson.jsonPOST(url, paquete);
            var paqueteprueba = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paquete);
            var respuestajson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objetoslistas.setPreferencesoutput>(respuesta.ToString());
            if (respuestajson.error == "")
            {
                Settings["timestamp"] = respuestajson.timestamp;
            }
        }
```

When I launch the emulator all seems to work ok, the checkboxes are marked or unmarked depending if the bool is true or false. But when I change the state of any of them placechange never wents to true. The fact is that if I look the full object the boolean array has changed. Any Idea?

Comment: Arrays do not provide notification facilities. Use ObservableCollection instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the array to an [observable collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which monitors and reports any internal *collection changes*, not just the reference to the collection has changed, and process that information as required.

### Update

See Muflar's answer below to see how to consume an observable collection to get notifications after things have been added.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I do it adding

```
_placeTypes.CollectionChanged += _placeTypes_CollectionChanged;
```

to the constructor and then the new method:

```
void _placeTypes_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.OldItems!=null)
        {
            placechange = true;
        }
    }
```

int the object